# Are "with a view to" and "with a view towards" synonymous?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I know that "with a view to x" means "with the intent of doing something", but I am not sure if "with a view towards x" means the same thing. I couldn't find an entry for "with a view towards", so I was wondering if it was idiomatic and they both meant the same thing. I think there might be a slight difference in meaning, but I am not sure what it could be.

For example:

> The military deployed soldiers in the region with a view to securing a
>   critical asset.
>
> The military deployed soldiers in the region with a view towards
>   securing a critical asset.

Comment: Yes, they both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean **mostly the same thing**.

Using **"to"** makes "securing a critical asset" as the only purpose of the deployment.

Using **"towards"**, "securing a critical asset" loses some significance (as compared to being the only purpose), since other objectives might be pursued also.